# PolicyKit password timeout

Tags: linux, sudo, authentication, authorization, policykit

I'm looking for a configuration option in PolicyKit that allows me to extend the time that needs to pass for a password to be requested again, in a similar way you can with `sudo`.

Looking at the [polkit manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/polkit.8.html) I could see that one can use `auth_admin_keep`, which will grant privileges for a particular action during "a brief period (e.g. five minutes)."

So I would like to know if a) this period is configurable and b) it can be extended across all the actions.

The final purpose here is of course to avoid having to enter the password too many times. The ideal solution that balances security and convenience would be to expire the password every (e.g.) fifteen minutes, no matter the actions you are trying to accomplish. For instance if you type `sudo echo x` in a terminal and you enter your password, if right after that you want to install some application using a graphical interface, you should not be prompted for your password again (unless it has expired).

Comment: The same question has been asked later in Unix & Linux -- https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/409636/99932. The answer is not very motivating though.

Comment: Gentoo users may put this patch into `/etc/portage/patches/sys-auth/polkit/30-minutes.patch` to change the delay: https://gist.github.com/PF4Public/cf223fa1f9614b92dba2b64474226fff